# Using a custom class in Godot

Tags: godot, gdscript

I have a simple network chat program created in Godot that I am using to teach basic encryption to high school students with. I would like to add a custom built encryption class to allow students to create their own cyphers. Here is a simple implementation I created to test the class:

```
class Security:
    extends Resource

    func _init():
        print("Started.")

    func encrypt():
        print("Encrypting.")
```

In my main script, I have this code to initialise the class (I have this at the top, in the variable space, before any function definition):

```
const Security = preload("res://scripts/security.gd")
var sec = Security.new()
```

And then this in one of my functions within the script:

```
func send_message():
    sec.encrypt()
```

At no point does either print message appear in the console. When I trigger the send_message function, I get the following error:

> Invalid call. Nonexistent function 'encrypt' in base 'Rederence (security.gd)'.

Is there something I am doing wrong with the creation of the class, or how I add it to my script? Or is what I am trying not really doable (e.g. should I just be adding a node, adding a script to that and using that node in my scene)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `class` syntax creates a inner class. That is `class Security` is not the class of the script.

As a consequence, when you do this:

```
const Security = preload("res://scripts/security.gd")
```

You are not getting the security class you defined. Instead it is a class that contains the class you defined.

You can instance your class like this:

```
var sec = Security.Security.new()
```

There the first `Security` is the name of the constant that refers to the class of the script. And the second `Security` is the inner class `Security` you defined.

See [Inner Classes](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/scripting/gdscript/gdscript_basics.html#inner-classes).

---

I suggest you define your class with `class_name` syntax:

```
class_name Security extends Resource

func _init():
    print("Started.")

func encrypt():
    print("Encrypting.")
```

*Notice also the change in indentation.*

Then the class will be global (which also means there is no need to `preload`), so you can simply do this:

```
var sec = Security.new()
```

*Again, no preload needed, the class is global.*

---

Alternatively, do not use a class name, instead have the functions directly on the script. And use preload:

*scurity.gd*:

```
extends Resource

func _init():
    print("Started.")

func encrypt():
    print("Encrypting.")
```

*Somewhere else*:

```
const Security = preload("res://scripts/security.gd")
var sec = Security.new()
```

Comment: Thanks, this exactly answered my question.